# Solve differential equation: $ \frac{dy}{dx}= e^{y+x} $ with the initial condition that y(0) = -ln(4)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve:

$ \frac{dy}{dx}= e^{y+x} $ with the initial condition that y(0) = -ln(4)?

First, I separated to $ \frac{dy}{(e^y)}= dx(e^x)$. Then I integrated both sides, which gave me:

$ - e^{-y} = e^x + K$.

Here I am stuck?

Comment: $- e^{-\ln 4} = e^0 + K$ ,

Answer (score 3):

You're almost there.  Given $e^{-y}=K-e^x$, we see that

$$y(0)=-\log(4)\implies e^{\log(4)}=K-1\implies K=5$$

Then, solving for $y$ we find that

$$y(x)=-\log(5-e^x)$$